# Celery stucks at pending

Tags: python, celery

This is my code:
`celery_app.py`

```py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery(
    'tasks', # app name
    broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', # broker URL
    backend='redis://localhost:6379/1', # backend URL
    include=['tasks'] # list of task modules
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

`tasks.py`

```py
from celery_app import app


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


result = add.delay(2, 5)
print(result.status)
result.get()
```

I run celery using this command:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=DEBUG
```

And the output is:

```
PENDING
```

I can see after running this code some new keys are created in redis.
For more information this is my docker-compose for redis:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
  redisinsight:
    image: redislabs/redisinsight:latest
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    environment:
      - REDISINSIGHT_REDIS_HOSTS=redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
  flower:
    image: mher/flower:0.9.7
    command: ['flower', '--broker=redis://redis:6379', '--port=5555']
    ports:
      - 5557:5555
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

What's wrong?